# Comment size limit and links

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

It is quite irritating that the links' urls in comments exhaust the character limit, especially in case of Area51 where entering one link to a proposal can almost take the whole of it (with the refer hash).

This can be of course omitted with an url shortener, but while the limit is already enforced by a JS script, I think it would be more elegant to modify it to ignore the link urls (and maybe also the rest of markdown formatting).

Comment: Are you talking about comments directly on the proposals, or comments in general?

Comment: @Jon The problem is general, but obviously it gets more serious when you have 150 chars instead of 600...

Comment: 2 years after, the issue is still present...

Comment: For reference, essentially the same feature requests was posted today: [discourage url shorteners in comments: don't add link's href size to the total comment size](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293/193139)

Comment: Furthermore, **`markdown` formatting characters** should also be exempted from being counted against *comments character limit*; they are supposed to add readability, but current implementation penalizes their generous usage

Answer (score 4):

- The Area51 links in question are only ~70 characters long -- I believe you can remove the slug of the proposal title from the URL, or at least shorten it to a single character (if not, then we should request that feature).
- As mentioned, you can use a URL-shortening service.
- The database has to store comments in their original (raw/Markdown) form to allow for comment editing. The *physical* field limit is currently 600 characters.
- The current comment character limit gives you 3 massive non-shortened links (say, 150 characters each) plus ~140 characters for the actual comment. Is that *really* not enough?
- If it isn't enough, there's nothing stopping you from spanning your comment over two or more physical comments.

I can see an argument for increasing the limit on proposal comments from 150 to, say, 300 characters, but I don't think there's a case for increasing anything beyond a 600-character limit.

Comment: See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93042/automatically-split-long-comments-into-two-if-att-can-why-cant-you/93043#93043) (10k+ only, unfortunately).

Comment: But [they discourage `URL shorteners`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320001/3679900) because of too many **broken links**