# Is it really so bad to use URL shorteners in comments, considering the character limit?

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks

I have noticed that Stack Overflow (and presumably other sites) don't like it when you place a shortened url from a third party in the comments, but there is a character limit in comments.

What if I need to include a very (very) long link?

Does the site count that against my character limit since I can't use an external URL shortener?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What if I need to include a very (very) long link?

You don't. If that very long link is so important it probably should go in an answer. If it is only temporary to help improve a post, create a chatroom (see [Shadow Wizards answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302694/158100) for the details) and post there or create a Gist on Github with the link and link to the gist.

> Does the site count that against my character limit since I can't use an external URL shortener?

Yes, there is no logic in place that detects if a comment contains a link and then suddenly increases the allowed limit. The backing field in the comments table only allow for 600 characters so whatever you type, it needs to fit in that field.

There is a feature request that asks for urls to be excluded from the comment character length limit: [discourage url shorteners in comments: don't add link's href size to the total comment size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267293/discourage-url-shorteners-in-comments-dont-add-links-href-size-to-the-total-c) which you might want to support.

Comment: Ok, I see. Hopefully this will help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

> What if I need to include a very (very) long link?

As already explained in [the other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302692/152859), posting shortened URL directly in comment is bad idea and likely to get flagged, no matter what the final URL is. However, I'll suggest an alternative.

Assuming the very very long link is meant for the post author, and that author is still active on the site and has more than 20 reputation, **you can invite them to chat** and post the link there. Chat is more flexible, and if the URL exceeds the message limit you can post shortened URL there.

Comment: Um, I don't mind you getting the rep, but I did mention *create a chatroom*. Is the terseness of that statement the reason you dedicated an whole answer to it?

Comment: @rene oh. Well, it's well hidden behind the general "no, don't do it" aura of the answer. Guess this answer can be considered as extension of yours then, adding some details about the chat option.

Comment: Okay, fair enough.