# Count length of comment only by the markdown formatted *result* length, not by its *raw input* length

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, hyperlinks, character-limit

When adding markdown formatted links, you have the chance to give a short and readable name to a link, using :

[image]

I have to change it to:

[image]

to be able to comment. [Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70512898/docker-volume-mariadb-has-root-permission):

[image]

If I try to save some space in a comment, I am sometimes forced to just post the link, without the short title, to get the text into the comment field, which makes the comment less readable.

Would it not be a better way to count only the length of the markdown result? The link is just the most important example, there are other markdown commands that also take space and should not be counted. And if this is just a technical issue, could that max comment field size be increased, without allowing to write more result text than now of course, just with the chance to use more markdown?

Comment: This is only tangential to the feature request, but I will point out that I often use shortened links to Stack Exchange posts such as `[How can I link to a specific answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45597)` or `[How can I link to a specific answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45597#305392)`. In fact, in [the answer I mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45597#305392) you can find a bookmarklet that can be used to create such links quickly. (In your example, using `[How can I use docker without sudo?](https://askubuntu.com/q/477551)` would save a few characters.)

Comment: @Martin I know that way of getting a short link from `Share`. But then you need to decide whether you take the link of a chosen answer or exactly the question link. In this case, I meant the whole Q/A site instead. Linking just to the question could make the reader think I meant the question content only. I get your point, though, there is a way to save a lot of link space by this.

Comment: I’ve written a user script that shortens these links even further. E.g.: `[Some link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/123/456)` or `[Some link on the same origin](/a/123/456)`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Nice, could help as a workaround, have you published it somewhere? Could be an answer here. Best would be to count the markdown *result* only.

Comment: I will add links to some related posts here on [meta.se]: [Can we stop counting link text in comment word-counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287407), [Discourage URL shorteners in comments: don't add link's href size to the total comment size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/267293) and maybe also [Formatting should not count towards the character limit on comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52976).

Comment: @questionto42 I haven’t published it yet, no.

Comment: @Martin Oh, did not see that. Is this probably a duplicate then of the last link. The first and second link are just about links, that is not far enough.

Comment: @SebastianSimon please do, I need it.

Comment: @SebastianSimon You could answer with that "tiny url" script at [Can we stop counting link text in comment word-counts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287407/can-we-stop-counting-link-text-in-comment-word-counts) perhaps, if you can spare the time.